# Setting values to nil - swift/parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, null

I have a UISwitch in my app which I want to register and unregister push notifications. I am currently using parse and I want the app to update to devicetoken in the usertable on the server as well. I'm using this code but it crashes when I flip the switch. 
"Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject."

So how would I deal with dropping the value from the current installation and usertable if I can't set to nil.

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
 switchValue.setOn(false, animated: true)
 installation.deviceToken = nil
 user["devicetoken"] = nil
 user.saveInBackground()
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `removeObjectForKey`on PFObject. that way when you get back same data from parse, you will get nil, not an empty string

Answer (score -1):

Just use `user["devicetoken"] = ""`, and be sure to check for a blank string before trying to use the token to send a notification.

Comment: He is writing this is Swift, not Objective-C.